# Determinant of a sum of square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&\cdots 0\\
0&0&1&\cdots 0\\
\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots 1 \\
1&1&1&\cdots1
 \end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}$$

i.e. it has ones above the main diagonal except for the last row and the last row has all ones.

> I am trying to find $\det(A+A^2+\cdots+A^t)$ for $t\leq n $ $\tag{1}$

I have checked that for a few $n$, $\det(A)=\det(A^2)=\cdots=\pm 1$. But I am not sure how to prove that. Also determinant of sum of matrices is not equal to sum of determinant of those matrices, so I'm not sure how to find $(1)$? Any ideas?

**EDIT:**I realize that it is hard to find exact value of $(1)$ and so an upper bound for $(1)$ is also useful to me.

Comment: It's straightfoward to show that $\det A = -1$ as I think you have worked out. Then note that $\det (AB) = \det A \det B$ and so it is then straightforward to show that $\det (A^n) = (-1)^n$. As for the rest, I'm rusty on linear algebra and don't immediately have a quick way to proceed here myself.

Comment: Are you sure that the last row is a row of $1$s rather than a row of $-1$s?

Comment: @user1551 Yes, the last low is a row of ones. Thanks.

Comment: @PrimeMover I see, true, thanks.

Comment: I haven't checked, but if $A-I$ is invertible, you could make use the geometric sum.

Comment: @dennis_s I know that $I+A+A^2+\cdots\to (I-A)^{-1}$ but I have a finite geometric sum and don't know what that sum is? Looks like $I-A$ is invertible.

Comment: When $n=2$, the numbers in $A^k$ are Fibonacci.

Comment: @manifolded In the prove of the convergence of the geometric series one shows that  $\sum_{k=0}^n A^k = (A^{n+1}-I)(A-I)^{-1}$ which could help.

Comment: I believe what dennis_s means is that the sum is equal to $A(I-A)^{-1}(I-A^t)$. Therefore the problem reduces to finding $\det(I_n-A^t)$ for $1\le t\le n$. However, having calculated $\det(I_n-A^t)$ for $1\le t\le n\le 7$, I don't see any pattern (except when $t=1,n-1$ or $n$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $$\lambda^n-\lambda^{n-1}-\lambda^{n-2}-\ldots-1=0$$.  This has one root $\lambda_1\approx2$, and all the other roots are inside the unit circle.
$$det(I-A^t)=\prod (1-\lambda_i^t)\approx (\lambda_1^t)\lt2^t$$

Comment: Thanks, I am out of touch with linear algebra. May I know how you got the characteristic poly of $A$? I know that it should be $\det(A-\lambda I)$ but not sure how that got simplified to $\lambda^n-\lambda^{n-1}-\lambda^{n-2}-...-1$? Thanks.

Comment: By induction.  Expand along the first row and $det(\lambda I-A_n)=\lambda det(\lambda I -A_{n-1})-1$

Comment: Makes sense now. How did you know that all the other roots are inside the unit circle?

Comment: Sorry, I got WolframAlpha to plot them  and they seemed to be.  Multiply by $\lambda-1$ and you get $\lambda^n=-\frac1{\lambda-2}$.  If they are to the left of $\lambda=1$ then the right-hand side is less than 1.

Comment: May I know why $\prod_i (1-\lambda_i^t)\approx \lambda_1^t$?

Comment: When $t$ gets large, several times $n$, the other $\lambda_i^t$ go to zero.  Before that, though, there is a significant factor that I haven't worked out...

Comment: The other $\lambda_i$ are near $n^{th}$ roots of $1$, so I think the product is near $n$ if $t$ is coprime to $n$ and smaller otherwise.  But $\det(1-A)$, which we also need, would also be near $n$.

Comment: Thanks, is there a heuristic behind why $\det(I-A)\approx n$? Numerically it does seem so.

Comment: Put $\lambda=1$ into $\lambda^n-\lambda^{n-1}-\ldots-1$

Comment: Last question. Is $\det(I-A^t)=\prod (1-\lambda_i^t)$ a known result? Thanks.

Comment: If $Av=\lambda v$ then $(I-A^t)v=v-AAA...Av=v-\lambda^tv$ so the eigenvalues are $1-\lambda_i^t$, and the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.